# How to do several consecutive intersect?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, intersect

I have a SQL query like below:

```sql
select col4, col5 from TableA where col1 = 'x'
intersect
select col4, col5 from TableA where col1 = 'y'
intersect
select col4, col5 from TableA where col1 = 'z'
```

How can I convert this SQL to PySpark equivalent?
I can create 3 DF and then do intersect like below:

```
df1 ==> select col4, col5 from TableA where col1 = 'x'
df2 ==> select col4, col5 from TableA where col1 = 'y'
df3 ==> select col4, col5 from TableA where col1 = 'z'

df_result = df1.intersect(df2)
df_result = df_result.intersect(df3)
```

But I feel that's not good approach to follow if I had more `intersect` queries.

Also, let's say [x,y,z] is dynamic, means it can be like [x,y,z,a,b,.....]

Any suggestion?

Comment: As it has tag of Apache-spark-sql so you can use your same sql query in Spark SQL

Comment: I want to use PySpark only, else the query will be very big.
This is just simple SQL I've provided here.
Just for single value changes like `x` or `y` or `z`, entire SQL query has to be appeded with intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do several consecutive `intersect`, there's `reduce`
available. Put all your dfs in one list and you will do intersect consecutively:

```py
from functools import reduce
dfs = [df1, df2,...]
df = reduce(lambda a, b: a.intersect(b), dfs)
```

But it would be inefficient in your case.

---

Since all the data comes from the same dataframe, I would suggest a rework. Instead of dividing df and then rejoining using `intersect`, do an aggregation and filtering.

Script (Spark 3.1):

```py
vals = ['x', 'y', 'z']
arr = F.array([F.lit(v) for v in vals])
df = df.groupBy('col4', 'col5').agg(F.collect_set('col1').alias('set'))
df = df.filter(F.forall(arr, lambda x: F.array_contains('set', x)))
df = df.drop('set')
```

Test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 11, 'y'),
     (1, 11, 'y'),
     (1, 11, 'x'),
     (2, 22, 'x'),
     (1, 11, 'z'),
     (4, 44, 'z'),
     (1, 11, 'M')],
    ['col4', 'col5', 'col1'])

vals = ['x', 'y', 'z']
arr = F.array([F.lit(v) for v in vals])
df = df.groupBy('col4', 'col5').agg(F.collect_set('col1').alias('set'))
df = df.filter(F.forall(arr, lambda x: F.array_contains('set', x)))
df = df.drop('set')

df.show()
# +----+----+
# |col4|col5|
# +----+----+
# |   1|  11|
# +----+----+
```

Comment: thank you for sharing. Yes, `reduce` isn't right approach for me, as I don't want to create multiple df.
I opted for 2nd one. Thank you.